# Use of R AllelicImbalance Package

Tags: r

I am a Bioinformatics student and pretty much an amateur R user. I have gone through almost the whole of the internet without getting any examples for the working of this package except the documentation provided by 'Bioconductor'-website. I am currently working on the 'AllelicImbalance' package provided by 'Bioconductor' for handling genomics data such as large 'BAM' files to find specific allelic positions and then analyzing them. I have gone ahead with their tutorial by creating a BAM format file. Then later to operate the file, I have set my working directory where my files have been saved.
The code for operating is -

```
> library(AllelicImbalance)
> searchArea<-GRanges(seqnames = c("17"), ranges = IRanges(79478301, 79478361))
> pathToFiles<-system.file("ERR009135.bam", package = "AllelicImbalance")
> reads<-impBamGAL(pathToFiles, searchArea, verbose=FALSE)
```

I get an error after the last command which says -

```
Error in .local(UserDir, ...) : No bam files found in 
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

The samples that I have used are present in here and are paired-end 'fastqc' files - ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR009/ERR009135
To download these files, a stable and fast internet connection is required. Later I converted these files to the 'BAM' format using the 'Linux' in the file 'ERR009135.bam'.

I would love to know if it is a general R syntax error or is it a major error where I need to make modifications with my files such as the 'BAM' files (ERR009135.bam). Please do reply with any suggestions or modifications. Will be deeply appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you convert the fastqc files into bam?  What genome/aligner did you use?

Comment: Sometimes (or should I say quite often?) the inconsistency on chromosome names leads to troubles ("17" or "chr17"). I'm not that familiar with 'AllelicImbalance', though.

Comment: @Feng : I used 'Bowtie2' to to create the BAM files. Then the human genome to align the samples with.